# Send a post request from an expressjs endpoint to django

Tags: django, express, axios, csrf

I am trying to implement the following workflow.

- Populate an html form
- Submit it
- The endpoint that is receiving the request(expressjs) does some processing and sends a request with the `req.body` to another backend(django)
- Django returns a response to expressjs

The problem is that I am being stuck at the csrf level and more specifically getting this error:

```
invalid csrf token
403
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
```

Here is the code that I am using for the request:

```
router.post('/registration', function (req, res, next) {

        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/register_extended/', JSON.stringify(req.body), {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('success')
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('failure')
        })

        res.send('respond with a resource');
    });
});
```

and here are my middlewares

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrfMiddleware);
```

How can I provide a valid csrf token for my needs? Axios is supposed to the handling itself, thats why I chose it.

Comment: Seems like you are not sending a request to django backend from another backend, but sending directly from the client. You first send a request to '/registration', and when that request succeeds, you send another request, this time I suppose to the Django backend, but still from the client. Is that correct?

Comment: No sure I get you. The /registration endpoint is the action called on submit. So when I enter the onsubmit procedure, I make another request as part of the process. When the second request return, I will then return to client (thats the plan)

Answer (score 0):

Django uses CSRF tokens to prevent CSRF attacks from untrusted domains. You can whitelist your site or IP where express is running to make post requests without a CSRF token. Add this to your Django 'settings.py':

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "yoursite.runningexpress.here.com"
]
```